# Widget inside a custom text editor in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, swt, widget

I'm developing a custom text editor for a programming language in Eclipse. Is it possible to put a widget (a button, for instance) inside a custom text editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all SWT related questions, always have a look at [the official Snippet page](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/) first. Often it is really helpful. This is one of these cases: [Snippet217](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet217.java?view=co) shows how to embed arbitrary controls in a `StyledText`, which seems to be what you aim for.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't directly awnser your question but I would recommend using http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/ (Xtext).  By defining a grammar for your programming language, Xtext generates a whole IDE for your language including an editor with syntax highlighting and auto-completion, an outline and hooks for builders etc.

It really is amazing, the first time I used it my jaw just dropped.